# Java - positioning label above GridLayout

Tags: java

I am trying to make a tic tac toe game, I've got a grid of buttons 3 x 3 but I want to have a bar just above them which displays the score and player names can someone please help I am very new to java and not sure where to start.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class NoughtsCrosses extends JFrame {
JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
JPanel scorePanel = new JPanel();
JButton button1 = new JButton("");
JButton button2 = new JButton("");
JButton button3 = new JButton("");
JButton button4 = new JButton("");
JButton button5 = new JButton("");
JButton button6 = new JButton("");
JButton button7 = new JButton("");
JButton button8 = new JButton("");
JButton button9 = new JButton("");
JLabel label = new JLabel("test");



public NoughtsCrosses(){
    super("Noughts & Crosses");
    setSize(400,400);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    gamePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

        gamePanel.add(button1);
        gamePanel.add(button2);
        gamePanel.add(button3);
        gamePanel.add(button4);
        gamePanel.add(button5);
        gamePanel.add(button6);
        gamePanel.add(button7);
        gamePanel.add(button8);
        gamePanel.add(button9);

    add(gamePanel);
    setVisible(true);
}



public static void main(String args[]){

    new NoughtsCrosses();

}



}
```

Comment: There's not any code there where you're trying to do that. What are you having problems with?

Comment: Wrap the cells panel in another panel which uses a BorderLayout, then you can add another panel to the NORTH position of panel with a BorderLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One such solution would be to set your JFrame to Border layout, then add a new JLabel in NORTH position and add the 3x3 grid in CENTER position.

Here is the java docs on using border layout

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html